# How to add dynamic destinations to camel?

Tags: apache-camel, publish-subscribe

I am new to Apache Camel. I am trying to build a pubsub pattern with Camel. I want to add subscribers dynamically so that a single event can be received by dynamic number of receivers. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example use JMS for that. I am its a bit cheap answer. But pub-sub is native supported by JMS.